# What tools are available to simulate certain network conditions on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, testing, traffic-shaping

In order to test our deployment I want to simulate certain network events like connection losses, timeout, limited bandwidths etc.

I already googled for this but haven't found something that really suited my needs. ipfw seems to be what I need but I can't seem to find an ipfw package for Ubuntu. Also I'd like to know whether there are alternatives or even better tools for my task.

Comment: You can use `iptables` and `tc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate those things with firewall.

Userland tool to modify firewall rules is called `iptables`

for example if you want to simulate 5 seconds of connection loss you can do this

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s source.ip.for.which.you.want.to.appear.to.timeout --dpor $port -j DROP ;`
`sleep 5;`
`iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -s source.ip.for.which.you.want.to.appear.to.timeout --dpor $port -j DROP ;`

Comment: Thanks! Pretty cool! Is there something equally elegant to simulate high latencies? I'd like to say "port 1234 has a latency of XXXXms".

Answer (score 0):

iptables is great, but some tools are sharper when dealing with this kind of problems.

- [Lagfactory](http://software.inl.fr/trac/wiki/LagFactory) (based on [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem))
- [nistnet](http://www.antd.nist.gov/tools/nistnet/faq.html). Old but powerful.
- [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

And also [wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/), not a standalone app but more a customized router distro.

Answer (score 0):

From the sister site Stack Overflow:  [Simulate delayed and dropped packets on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux)